# scrollBy() invoked through execute_script is not working on chrome store page using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, js-scrollby

I'm using selenium with python 3 and Chrome driver. I'm trying to perform a scroll in a chrome store URL.

This one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-game-zone-new-tab/abalcghoakdcaalbfadaacmapphamklh

No matter what I tried - the site doesn't scroll. Tried running "window.scrollBy" and "window.scrollTo".
Tried clicking on "body" first, and other elements - nothing.

current code:

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500)")
```

What could be the problem? I don't want to send a "down" key or "page down" since I believe I'll need to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe the [chrome store page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-game-zone-new-tab/abalcghoakdcaalbfadaacmapphamklh) the page have a header that is fixed to the top of the page. So when the *window* object is invoked, the focus jumps at the top of the page, leaving the *document* behind the fixed header.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Additionally, at times ChromeDriver is pretty fast and the `scrollTo()` action fires before Chrome's default scroll to html anchor event. In these cases, a possible solution would be to induce some delay as follows:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, y);},1)
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [JavaScript issue with scrollTo() in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691569/javascript-issue-with-scrollto-in-chrome)

As an alternative, to perform a [scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) within the chrome store [URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-game-zone-new-tab/abalcghoakdcaalbfadaacmapphamklh) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` of your choice and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based solution:

- Using [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354364/scrollintoview-method-implementation/59356940#59356940):

  ```
  driver.get('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-game-zone-new-tab/abalcghoakdcaalbfadaacmapphamklh')
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Related']"))))
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Related]

Comment: Thank you so much for that! But how can I use this to preform a scrollBy? What if I need to only scroll by a specific amount? Is that possible to do by "length" and not by specific element?

Comment: And one more thing - why was waiting for the site to load usind sleep() is not enough? I waited far longer after the site was loaded, so what is the difference from the until() function?

Comment: @OronW Checkout the updated answer and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I have a lot to read now (in a good way) and I hope what you wrote would make it all much more clear. I had no idea such problems can occur. This answer is very clear and answers everything for me so I've accepted it. Now I'll start with the "homework" I got from it...

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling an element into view seems to be working fine on that webpage. Here's an example:

```
footer=driver.find_element_by_class_name('e-f-ra-gj')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", footer)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! But how can I use this to preform a scrollBy? What if I need to only scroll by a specific amount? Is that possible to do by "length" and not by specific element?

Comment: It's simply a more reliable and portable approach than `scrollTo` in my opinion, given that you are stepping into JavaScript realm with Python's `driver.execute_script`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've accepted DebanjanB answer since it's more detailed and answered everything I wanted. I do agree with you that it might be better to use an element, but I might need sometimes just a specific scroll. Thanks again!